# Uber Api GET /me using Curl is not working

Tags: php, curl, uber-api

I am trying to implement Uber Api GET /me

```
Ref :- https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/me-get

They specified that :- Replace <TOKEN> in the example below with a user access token    

curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
         -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
         -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
         'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/me'

I have write the above code in curl, but I am always getting "Error":"No authentication provided.","code":"unauthorized"

My Curl code is

<?php

    // Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/me");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer <token>";       #<token> has been replaced by my token
    $headers[] = "Accept-Language: en_US";      
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo "<li>".$httpcode;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);

I am always getting "Error":"No authentication provided.","code":"unauthorized"

Still this is not working. Is Uber Api stops working today ?
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on research, finally I am able to get the solution.Uber returns

```
get
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/me

Array
(
    [0] => Authorization: Token <My token>
    [1] => Accept-Language: en_US
    [2] => Content-Type: application/json
)
{"error":true,"message":"We have experienced a problem.","code":500,"content":null}
```

So Uber is having issue. Wasted a lot of time

Comment: Are you sure you are providing your token correctly in the authorization? I was just able to return information correctly, and the first thing you posted (the error code no auth provided) implies you were not authorizing properly. Make sure you have the 'profile' scope checked for your token. I also replied to your question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/uber-developers/ccYviz9rVZY

Comment: Checked with Uber. Everything was correct. It was the issue from the Uber.

Comment: Our Uber account was also deleted suddenly. Will email details there in email

Comment: I have emailed you on same group. You can see the email and issue regards deleting automatically. After recreating account, the above code was working.(I have changed the new token)...

Comment: Uber did not delete the account. Will take further comment on that thread.